# How to set Security Mode to Transport

Tags: javascript, api, wcf-security

Trying to make a basic SOAP call to test a vendor's API and see their data response (Documentation doesn't have it.)

When I try, I am getting a response of

> The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to
>   a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender
>   and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).

Which the API Provider said is due to my Security Mode being set to Transport - I am not sure what that means in the terms of using A) POSTMAN B) A generic Node script to query using Request/Popsicle etc.

Comment: Do you know what security mode you are supposed to have?

Comment: @Jclangst Transport

Comment: Ok. So to clarify, you are trying to have your security mode set to Transport?

Comment: @Jclangst Yes, according to support team that is my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have `Transport` security, usually all that means is switching to tls via `https` versus standard `http` to make your requests (though there are other, less common forms of `Transport` security). For mode libraries and utilities, this will happen automatically if you just specify the url with `https`.

Comment: Yea, it's being enforced with https, and I tried having POstman force TLS, HTTPS, and SSL (Just to test) and I am forcing HTTPS via the Node script, and getting same response.

Comment: Are you positive they don't want you do to `TransportWithMessageCredential` security? Without knowing who your API provider is and how they have configured their server, all I can assume based on your question is that they want TLS security. It sounds like there might be some miscommunication between you and them -- I'd try to contact them again asking for the exact binding, protocol, and security mechanism that they are looking for. I cannot provide any more insight until I know that.

Comment: I have reached out to them to clarify, and get the exact information. Thanks for the insight; I'll update once replied.